# wordpress .htaccess rename url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am not sure if this would be a rename thing? 
Can I have my urls display from

```
myweb/l2/la
myweb/l2/lb
myweb/l2/lc
myweb/l2/ld
```

to

```
myweb/la
myweb/lb
myweb/lc
myweb/ld
```

I've never done this before, if someone could help? I'd like to write the rule in .htaccess.
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what this has to do with wordpress, but how you have wordpress setup will probably affect what kind of solution will work.

To change what is displayed in the browser's URL address bar, you'd do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /l2/([^\ \?]+)
RewriteRule ^l2/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

The internally change them back (without redirecting the browser), you'd need:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /l2/$1 [L]
```

If you have wordpress rules that route to an index.php, you'd want these rules **before** your wordpress routing rules.

Comment: thank you! does this affect to all pages ? actually, I only wanted to change few pages

Comment: @olo it will affect all pages, if you want it to only affect certain pages (e.g. the 4 in your example), then you need to replace the `(.*)` in the rule's pattern with `(la|lb|lc|ld)`.

Comment: got `Server error!` once I put this `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /l2/([^ \?]+)`

Comment: @olo Forgot to escape that space, the `([^ \?]+)` should be `([^\ \?]+)`

Comment: one more question if my structure like `myweb/l2/l2/la` `myweb/l2/l2/lb` should I do `RewriteRule ^/l2/(l2)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(l2)$ /l2/$1 [L]` Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @olo you would: `RewriteRule ^l2/l2/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]` and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /l2/l2/$1 [L]`